# Nil return where it should be exist a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm playing on rails console and did the following steps:

```
agendamento = Agendamento.last
```

And got a record that looks like this

```
#<Agendamento id: 4, sala_id: 2, name: "Delta C", start_at: "2013-10-11 02:00:00", end_at:     "2013-10-10 04:00:00", bookingDate: "2013-10-10",
 bookingTime: "2000-01-01 23:00:00", bookingDuration: 2, approved: true, usuario_id: nil,     created_at: "2013-10-05 02:24:00", updated_at: "2013-
10-05 02:24:00">
```

when I do `agendamento.name` I receive:

```
Delta C
```

and it works in all values, but not on `sala_id`, `agendamento.sala_id` returns

```
nil
```

This attribute is acessible in the model, why it is returning nil ?

Environment: Ruby 2 and Rails 4

Comment: If `sala_id` is a foreign key reference, have you tried invoking `sala` instead? Maybe that will give you the related object.

Comment: Feel free to up-vote and accept my newly-created answer, then. :-)

Comment: Yeah, but, AFAIK, sala_id should still return the id.

Answer (score 1):

If `sala_id` is a foreign key reference, have you tried invoking `sala` instead? That should give you the related object.